Show that among the numbers $x_{1}, x_{2} ,...,x_n $there are two whose product is at most equal to $- 1 / n$.
the question
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 3,$ and $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n = 0$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2 = 1$.
Show that among the numbers $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n $there are two whose product is at most equal to $- 1 / n$.
the idea
So basically we have to show that there are 2 numbers $i,j \geq 3$ such that $x_ix_j\leq -\dfrac{1}{n}$.
We can rearange WLOG the numbers just so $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq ...\leq x_n$.
We notice that at least one of the numbers is negative, because all of them cant be positive.
I thought of supposing that there arent such numbers and try demonstrating otherwise.
I thought of some inequalities given the fact that we know the sum of the numbers and the sum of their squares, but I got to nothing useful...
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

@Anne lol we made the exact same error.

I deleted it before I amended that bit. What I mean is, we made the same faulty argument.

@AnneBauval i dont really understand what they meant

Try again more deeply. Follow @WimC's answer, which is elementary, and post a comment below it if there still remains some step you don't follow.

@ioveri $-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}>-\frac{1}{n}$

Is it required that the pair are distinct, i.e. $x_ix_j\le -\frac{1}{n}$ with $i\ne j$?

@JoshuaTilley Since $x_i^2 \geq 0$, it is implied that the pair will be distinct.

@CalvinLin Good point :D

@IONELABUCIU I advised you to leave a comment below WimC's answer. I agree with @DS's comment about the bounty you proposed instead.
